# System.InvalidOperationException: Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first message on windows 7 machine

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, windows-runtime

I have a WPF application running without any issues in my windows 8 OS development machine. But when i try to run the same in Windows 7 machine i am getting the error

System.InvalidOperationException: Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first.

The detailed error log is

```
        [CDATA[Set property 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Style' threw an exception.
            LoadBaml at offset 481 in file:line:column <filename unknown>:0:0

            System.InvalidOperationException: Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first.
               at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ChangeLogicalParent(DependencyObject newParent)
               at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.AddLogicalChild(Object child)
               at System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.OnContentChanged(Object oldContent, Object newContent)
               at System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.OnContentChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
               at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
               at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
               at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
               at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
               at System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyStyleOrTemplateValue(FrameworkObject fo, DependencyProperty dp)
               at System.Windows.StyleHelper.InvalidateContainerDependents(DependencyObject container, FrugalStructList`1& exclusionContainerDependents, FrugalStructList`1& oldContainerDependents, FrugalStructList`1& newContainerDependents)
               at System.Windows.StyleHelper.DoStyleInvalidations(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, Style oldStyle, Style newStyle)
               at System.Windows.StyleHelper.UpdateStyleCache(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, Style oldStyle, Style newStyle, Style& styleCache)
               at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnStyleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
               at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
               at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
               at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
               at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
               at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
               at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
               at System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfKnownMemberInvoker.SetValue(Object instance, Object value)
               at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(XamlMember member, Object obj, Object value)
               at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(Object inst, XamlMember property, Object value)]]
```

I have no idea which element XAML or code behind causing this issue. Any help to find out reason for this strange issue?

Finally able to find the reason for error 
I have a ToggleButton style in the application which is defined in App.xaml like this

```
  <Style x:Key="ONStateLabelLib" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#A1A1A1"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>

        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"></Setter>

        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="45"></Setter>


        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>

        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="OFFStateLabelLib" TargetType="Label">

        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"></Setter>

        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="ExtraLight"/>

        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#515151"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#393939"></Setter>


        <Setter Property="Width" Value="45"></Setter>

        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#A1A1A1"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"></Setter>


        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="OnOffToggleStyleLib" TargetType="ToggleButton" >
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="90"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <ContentPresenter  VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent">
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Content">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DockPanel Margin="0">
                            <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ONStateLabelLib}" >YES</Label>
                            <Label Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=OFFStateLabelLib}" >NO</Label>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Content">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DockPanel Margin="0">
                            <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=OFFStateLabelLib}">YES</Label>
                            <Label Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ONStateLabelLib}" >NO</Label>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

And i use the Toggle Button in 2 pages Page1.xaml and Page2.xaml like this

```
  <ToggleButton Margin="5" Grid.Row="0" 
     ToolTip="{Binding Path=localResource.reader_tooltip_settings_fullscreen,Source={StaticResource      DbookLanguageManagerDynamic}}"  Grid.Column="1"
     Name="btn_fullScreen" Click="btn_fullScreen_Clicked"
      Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=OnOffToggleStyleLib}" />
```

Application Loads Page1.xaml first and While Navigating to Page2.xaml i ma getting above exception .

Now can some one help to solve this?

Comment: Seems to me you're setting a property that holds controls within a style, somewhere in your application. You might try setting the `ContentTemplate` in case it's a `Content` property causing this error. As for the source of the issue, the error simply does not give enough information for us to know it's origin since it's a compiled XAML. You're not able to debug on the W7 machine?

Comment: On the machine other than the development machine, make sure that you have installed all the pre-requisites. Also, Install Visual Studio on that machine. And then try to run your exe on that machine. Now if you get any errors, then you can choose to debug using Visual Studio and I think you might catch that error in a very short period of time. Good luck.........

Comment: Yes i been able to debug on windows 7 machine . But no more information available like which xaml is causing it or line of error etc

Comment: @Vishal IS it a good way to ask customer to install visual studio while deploy a project in client side?

Comment: No, its not a good way to ask customer to install visual studio. But this should be the testing period for you and provide some assemblies (dlls) with your setup file, so that clients do not need to install visual studio. I am not any expert but still you should wait for other responses.

Comment: I second that it's *not* a good idea to ask customers to install Visual Studio. Instead of that, you'll need to implement some pretty extensive logging.

Comment: @Sheridan@Vishal@hantoun Question edited with reason of exception . Can some one help to sort it out now?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `Content` property setter to `ContentTemplate`, and using a `DataTemplate` as value:

```
<Style
    x:Key="OnOffToggleStyleLib"
    TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter
        Property="VerticalAlignment"
        Value="Center"></Setter>
    <Setter
        Property="Width"
        Value="90"></Setter>
    <Setter
        Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate
                TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <ContentPresenter
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger
                        Property="IsMouseOver"
                        Value="True">
                        <Setter
                            Property="Background"
                            Value="Transparent">
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger
            Property="IsChecked"
            Value="True">
            <Setter
                Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel
                            Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label
                                DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                                Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ONStateLabelLib}">YES</Label>
                            <Label
                                Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=OFFStateLabelLib}">NO</Label>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger
            Property="IsChecked"
            Value="False">
            <Setter
                Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel
                            Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label
                                DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                                Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=OFFStateLabelLib}">YES</Label>
                            <Label
                                Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ONStateLabelLib}">NO</Label>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I also swapped the `DockPanel` with a `StackPanel`, it's a better approach in my opinion. Let me know if it works :)

Comment: Yes it worked . BUt i just want to know few more about why its failing for few versions of windows only ?? Can you please help to explain it bit more the reason for error??

Comment: That's something I really like to know either... I've had the same issue a while ago, but instead of throwing an exception (like I read online) the application refused to display a control's content. Unfortunately I can only give you a solution, perhaps somebody else can enlighten us about the cause of the issue.