# Getting System.InvalidOperationException on WIndows 7 machines while reusing a custom style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-runtime

I have a WPF ToggleButton  with some specific Style rules  and i am using the same style Toggle Button in different pages of my application.
Here is the ToggleButton

```
<ToggleButton Margin="5" Grid.Row="0" 
 ToolTip="{Binding Path=localResource.reader_tooltip_settings_fullscreen,Source={StaticResource  DbookLanguageManagerDynamic}}"  Grid.Column="1"
Name="btn_fullScreen" Click="btn_fullScreen_Clicked"
Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=OnOffToggleStyleLib}" />
```

Here is  the style for this ToggleButton

```
  <Style x:Key="ONStateLabelLib" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#A1A1A1"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>

    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"></Setter>

    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="45"></Setter>


    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>

    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="OFFStateLabelLib" TargetType="Label">

    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"></Setter>

    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="ExtraLight"/>

    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#515151"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#393939"></Setter>


    <Setter Property="Width" Value="45"></Setter>

    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#A1A1A1"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"></Setter>


    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="OnOffToggleStyleLib" TargetType="ToggleButton" >
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="90"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <ContentPresenter  VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent">
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DockPanel Margin="0">
                        <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ONStateLabelLib}" >YES</Label>
                        <Label Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=OFFStateLabelLib}" >NO</Label>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DockPanel Margin="0">
                        <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=OFFStateLabelLib}">YES</Label>
                        <Label Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ONStateLabelLib}" >NO</Label>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Now the issue is **

*> when i try to load the Page2.xaml from Page1.xaml i am getting the

> below exception  but only in Windows 7 machines [ Home or Ultimate
>   editions ] . On windows 7 Pro , windows 8 all versions there is no
>   issues at all.*

**

```
Set property 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Style' threw an exception.
        LoadBaml at offset 481 in file:line:column <filename unknown>:0:0

        System.InvalidOperationException: Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first.
           at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ChangeLogicalParent(DependencyObject newParent)
           at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.AddLogicalChild(Object child)
           at System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.OnContentChanged(Object oldContent, Object newContent)
           at System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.OnContentChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
           at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
           at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
           at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
           at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
           at System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyStyleOrTemplateValue(FrameworkObject fo, DependencyProperty dp)
           at System.Windows.StyleHelper.InvalidateContainerDependents(DependencyObject container, FrugalStructList`1& exclusionContainerDependents, FrugalStructList`1& oldContainerDependents, FrugalStructList`1& newContainerDependents)
           at System.Windows.StyleHelper.DoStyleInvalidations(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, Style oldStyle, Style newStyle)
           at System.Windows.StyleHelper.UpdateStyleCache(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, Style oldStyle, Style newStyle, Style& styleCache)
           at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnStyleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
           at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
           at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
           at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
           at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
           at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
           at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
           at System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfKnownMemberInvoker.SetValue(Object instance, Object value)
           at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(XamlMember member, Object obj, Object value)
           at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(Object inst, XamlMember property, Object value)
```

Any idea bout the reason for this error ? I tried x:Shared="False" on style but no difference

Comment: Some *strange* issues sometimes disappears after running Windows Update.

Comment: Perhaps i found a solution on another thread [ raised by me only before knowing the reason of exception] And see answer here that solves the issue. But reason for error is still unknown . Please help if you can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26275054/system-invalidoperationexception-specified-element-is-already-the-logical-child/26294150?noredirect=1#comment41258581_26294150